# Microsoft graph ErrorMultipleMailboxesNotSupportedForRest error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to copy a mail using the Microsoft Graph API and Postman. I'm copying a mail from my personal work mailbox to a shared mailbox folder using this POST URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/xxx-my-id-xxx/messages/xxx-a-message-id/copy, the body of the request = { "destinationId": "xxx-id-of-target-folder-in-shared-maibox-xxxx" } This has worked for years using the deprecated outlook v2.0 API, but until recent, I get this error: "error": { "code": "ErrorMultipleMailboxesNotSupportedForRest", "message": "Rest does not support copying items between multiple mailboxes, only single mailbox copy operations are supported." }. I tried switching to the graph API but keep getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?
Upon authentication, I use the following OAuth2 scopes: openid Mail.ReadWrite.Shared offline_access profile email

Comment: If you're using older Outlook v2.0 API then consider moving to Microsoft Graph API, thats the recommendation moving forward. In case if you think the feature doesn't exists in Microsoft Graph API, then consider upvoting [Microsoft Uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39627928-message-copy-allow-to-copy-message-to-another-mai), so that can be considered to be implemented or you can file a new one as well.

Comment: In addition, please do share the following: (1) Share the requestid, timestamp of the error response that you get.(2) Outside of sharedmailbox, if you try copying from MSA mailbox to M365 mailbox works in Graph explorer?

Comment: Apparently copying mail message from a personal to a shared mailbox is no longer supported in the Microsoft Graph API, see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/306565/microsoft-graph-errormultiplemailboxesnotsupported.html. This was possible in the Outlook v2.0 API. I've upvoted https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/35630110-please-provide-move-mail-functionality-across-ma in the hope MSFT will include this feature